# how to make pop up with dimmer close

Tags: popup

```
<div>
  <style>
    .dim {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        position:fixed;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        z-index:1 !important;
        background-color:black;
        filter: alpha(opacity=75);        /* internet explorer */
                -khtml-opacity: 0.75;     /* khtml, old safari */
                -moz-opacity: 0.75;       /* mozilla, netscape */
                opacity: 0.75;            /* fx, safari, opera */
    }

    .wrapper { 
    width: 100%; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 5; 
    display: block;  
    }

    .popup { width: 400px;
    height: 200px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 40px; 
    background-color: #fff; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    color: #333; 
    }
  </style>

<div class="dim"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="popup">
Subscribe box</div>
</div>
</div>
```

here's the code I actually got from another post and it makes the pop up for the most part and it dims the screen but it doesn't close or have a close button so there's no way of closing it once it's opened. so add a close button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your going to have to do a little JavaScript to get this to work, so that the code can detect the click event on the close button.  I have previously used [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) to handle popups as it has quite a large number of features and is well documented, although you could also create your own using CSS3 and use javascript to add or remove a class.

Something like:

```
<style>
#basicElement {
    /* style here */ 
}
#basicElement.open {
  /* style here */ 
  animation: popup 25s linear;
  -moz-animation: popup 25s linear;
  -ms-animation: popup 25s linear;
  -o-animation: popup 25s linear;
  -webkit-animation: popup 25s linear;
}
#basicElement.closed { 
  /* style here */ 
  animation: popup 25s linear;
  -moz-animation: popup 25s linear;
  -ms-animation: popup 25s linear;
  -o-animation: popup 25s linear;
  -webkit-animation: popup 25s linear;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  -moz-direction: reverse;
  -ms-direction: reverse;
  -o-direction: reverse;
  -webkit-direction: reverse;
}
@-webkit-keyframes popup {
    0% {
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
    100% {
        background-size: 130% 130%;
        background-position: center bottom;
    }
}
</style>
<script>
$('#open').click(function (){ $(this).removeClass('closed').addClass('open'); });
$('#close').click(function (){ $(this).removeClass('open').addClass('closed'); });
</script>
```